# For cannizarro reaction is it necessary that carbonyl compounds don't have alpha hydrogen?

Tags: oxygen

Till date, I have encountered carbonyl compounds without alpha hydrogens that can undergo Cannizzaro reaction. But recently I came across the following molecule and I can't understand the reason behind why it shows Cannizzaro reaction.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. Do you have a reference or some more details on this reaction?

Comment: In addition to user55119's request in the comments, can you give aexample with a reference how ketones without $\alpha$-hydrogen under goes Cannizarro reaction without having a hydrogen to transfer to the second ketone?

Comment: Cannizzaro reaction requires an aldehyde in the first place. Is this an aldehyde? Yes and no.